# en0とen4を同時にキャプチャして１つのファイルとして出力する方法

Tags: macos, tcpdump, wireshark

Wiresharkのように、en0とen4を同時にキャプチャして１つのファイルとして出力する方法を模索しています。
en0とen4を同時にキャプチャし、en0はモニターモードにすべく、下記のように書いてみました。

tcpdump -Ini en0 -w  WLAN.pcap -W1 -G30 & tcpdump -i en4 -w  LAN.pcap -W1 -G30 & iperf -c 192.168.0.100 -i 1 -t30 -f m >> iperf.txt

しかし、ファイルが別々になってしまう、という点で、期待する動作ではありません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 追記

回答後に、質問内容が編集され「en0はモニターモードに」という前提条件が追加されていますが、以下の方法はWi-Fiインタフェースをモニターモードに設定するための `-I` オプションと併用することはできません。

---

`os-x` のタグが付いているので OS X 固有の回答です。

OS X 10.9（Darwin 13.0）以降であれば、tcpdump を以下のように実行することで複数インタフェースをキャプチャできます。

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i pktap,en0,en4 -w mix.pcap
```

ポイントは、`-i` オプションのインタフェース指定で、キャプチャしたい複数のインタフェースを `pktap` に続けてカンマ区切りで列挙することです。これで複数のインタフェースを同時にキャプチャできます。

なお、OS X 付属の tcpdump のマニュアルに記載されているように、この機能は OS X（Darwin）固有の PKTAP という疑似インタフェースを利用しているため、他のOSでは使えません。

> -i     Listen on interface.
>
> If the -D flag is supported, an interface number as printed by that flag can be used as the interface argument.
>
> On Darwin systems version 13 or later, when the interface is unspecified, tcpdump will use a pseudo interface to capture packets on a set of interfaces determined by the kernel  (excludes  by  default loopback and tunnel interfaces).
>
> Alternatively, to capture on more than one interface at a time, one may use "pktap" as the interface parameter followed by an optional list of comma separated interface names to include.  For example, to capture on the loopback and en0 interface:
>
> ```
> tcpdump -i pktap,lo0,en0
> ```
>
> An interface argument of "all" or "pktap,all" can be used to capture packets from all interfaces, including loopback and tunnel interfaces.
>
> A pktap pseudo interface provides for packet metadata using the default PKTAP data link type and files are written in the Pcap-ng file format.  The RAW data link type must be used to force to use  the legacy pcap-savefile(5) file format with a ptkap pseudo interface.  Note that captures on a ptkap pseudo interface will not be done in promiscuous mode.
>
> An  interface  argument of "iptap" can be used to capture packets from at the IP layer.  This capture packets as they are passed to the input and output routines of the IPv4 and IPv6 protocol handlers of the networking stack.  Note that captures will not be done in promiscuous mode.
>
> On other OSes, if unspecified, tcpdump searches the system interface list for the lowest numbered, configured up interface (excluding loopback).  Ties are broken by choosing the earliest match.
>
> On Linux systems with 2.2 or later kernels, an interface argument of "any" can be used to capture packets from all interfaces.  Note that captures on the "any" device will not be done in promiscuous mode.

Answer (score 1):

WiresharkをインストールしてコマンドラインI/F(`tshark`)を使う

`% tshark -i 1 2 -F pcap -w output.file`

`-i` に指定するのはI/F名か`-D`を指定して得られるI/F一覧の番号

もしくは、tcpdumpを2個動かして取得したファイルをWiresharkでマージする。GUIでやるほかにもmergecapというコマンドラインツールもあるようです。

Comment: tcpdumpではインターフェースが１つしか指定できないですが、tsharkであれば複数インターフェースを指定出来るのですね！

Answer (score 0):

以下ができるようになってます。

```
# tshark -i enp1s0f0 -i enp1s0f1
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on 'enp1s0f0' and 'enp1s0f1'
```